# My IP checker is checking if IP is technically valid, I want to check if it's online

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, ip

```
import socket

def is_valid_ipv4_address(address):
    try:
        socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET, address)
    except AttributeError:  # no inet_pton here, sorry
        try:
            socket.inet_pton()
        except socket.error:
            return False
        return address.count('.') == 3
    except socket.error:  # not a valid address
        return False

    return True

def is_valid_ipv6_address(address):
    try:
        socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET6, address)
    except AttributeError:  # no inet_pton here, sorry
        try:
            socket.inet_pton()
        except socket.error:
            return False
        return address.count('.') == 3
    except socket.error:  # not a valid address
        return False

    return True

def checkStatus():
    websiteToCheck = input("Enter IP: ").replace(" ", "")
    if is_valid_ipv4_address(websiteToCheck) or is_valid_ipv6_address(websiteToCheck):
        print("Valid")
    elif len(websiteToCheck) == 0:
        print("Please input something")
    else:
        print("Invalid")

checkStatus()
```

It gives the expected output when it's not valid, like when the number is over 255, when the input contains letters of the alphabet etc.. However, let's say I input 10.111.111.111 as my IP. It prints "Valid", even though if you tried to access that IP right now you'd fail.

How do I check if an IP is online as opposed to whether it's numerically valid?

Comment: Define "online". Does it need to offer a publicly accessible server/port in order to count as "online"…? If so which one?

Comment: @deceze The person running the program should be able to enter that IP into their browser and have something other than a 404 load

Comment: A 404 already indicates a running HTTP server, which is very much "online". So you expect the IP to be running an HTTP server? Or an HTTP server which will serve a 2xx response?

Comment: And BTW, `address.count('.') == 3` for an *IPv6* address?!

Comment: @deceze I have no idea what a 2xx response is, but the idea is that the IP should give you a webpage which isnt a 404

Comment: @deceze also I'll remove that address count thingo from ipv6

Comment: Do you know what a 404 is? It is the response of a web server of which you have requested a nonsense URL. That already means that there is a web server running at that IP address, which should very much satisfy your "online" requirement. A 2xx (meaning 200, 201 etc.) is a *success* response code of an HTTP server. The opposite of "online" isn't "404", it would be *"connection error"*.

Comment: @deceze Ah. Yeah, I would want my IP to give a success response code. How would I do this?

Comment: Make an HTTP request to the IP, e.g. https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/urllib.request.html

Answer (score 1):

You cannot know if the IP can be accessed by simply looking at it. You will need to try to connect or ping it. The latter one is quite easy, although not 100% accurate (not all IPs respond to ping)

A quick way:

```
import os
response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + address)

#check the response...
if response == 0:
  return True
else:
  return False
```

Comment: Being able to respond to ping does not mean that the IP address in question is actually running a web server on port 80.

Comment: @tripleee: true, but it does answer the question "How do I check if an IP is online", does it not? The web server part came later on.

Comment: This unfortunately seems to be a recurring problem with these poorly-specified beginner questions.  Either way, there are multiple duplicates with good answers to both questions.

Comment: @tripleee: that unfortunate, but I'll still try to provide helpful answers.